# Change Link Text in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the following HTML:

```
<td class="  column-url"><a href="https://meine-homepage/wp/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/wohnung_nr_2.pdf" 
target="_self">https://meine-hompage/wp/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/wohnung_nr_2.pdf</a></td>
```

Now i want to change the Link-Text in Text-String "PDF"

I Tryed the following jquery. But i got no results:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

$(".column-url a").text("PDF");

});
</script>
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the element *td* inside *table* then it should work. I also believe that you have space before the *class* name unintentionally in HTML:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="column-url"><a href="https://meine-homepage/wp/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/wohnung_nr_2.pdf" 
    target="_self">https://meine-hompage/wp/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/wohnung_nr_2.pdf</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $(".column-url a").text("PDF");
  });
</script>
```